# Python : include last element (where i=0) when iterating in reverse

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I have a string `string = 'cbAfeDihGlkJonMrqPutS'` and I would like to iterate through it in order to yield `'AbcDefGhiJklMnoPqrStu'`.

I am using the following for loop to achieve `'DefGhiJklMnoPqrStu`, however the expected `Abc` is missing.

```
for i in (range(0, len(string), 3)):
    print(string[i+2 : i-1 : -1], end='')
```

This seems to be a problem due the `-1` in my ending element  `: i-1 :`, however I am wondering why iterating in reverse (with a step size of `-1`) and using `:i-1:` to capture the first element (where i=0) does not work similarly to iterating forwards and using `: i+1 :` for capturing the last element.

I am able to achieve my desired solution with

```
for i in (range(0, len(string), 3)):
    print(string[i:i+3:1][::-1], end='')
```

but iterating forwards and printing backwards seems like a clunky way to do it.  Having to add `[::-1]` seems like an otherwise superfluous step, were `[i+2 : i-1 : -1]` to have worked.

Is there are cleaner way to do this, other than `[i:i+3:1][::-1]` ?

Comment: `''.join(sorted(list(string), key=str.lower))`

Comment: ''.join(sorted(string , key=str.casefold)) should produce the result you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most elegant way to do it is probably to use `''.join()` and a comprehension to compress the loop you already came up with into a single line.

```
string = 'cbAfeDihGlkJonMrqPutS'
print(''.join(string[i:i+3][::-1] for i in range(0, len(string), 3)))
# AbcDefGhiJklMnoPqrStu
```

You'd think you'd be able to get rid of the extra `[::-1]` by doing like `string[i+2:i-1:-1]`, but as you've observed, this cuts off the first character in the string. This is a quirk of slice syntax the `end` bound of the slice is *exclusive* rather than inclusive, but at the same time an index of `-1` refers to the end of the string rather than 'the character before the beginning' (which would be out of bounds in, say, Java, but in which we wouldn't have this problem). To my knowledge, there's no way around this.

You could also try using `reversed()` instead of `[::-1]`, but I don't think that makes it any simpler or quicker:

```
print(''.join(c for i in range(0, len(string), 3) for c in reversed(string[i:i+3])))
```

---

EDIT: As @don't talk just code pointed out in a comment, it actually *is* possible to circumvent the problem, as putting `None` as the second argument of a slice will make the slice proceed to whichever end of the list is appropriate (until this comment I did not know this). With that in mind, we can indeed do the thing in only one slice:

```
print(''.join(string[i+2:i-1 if i else None:-1] for i in range(0, len(string), 3)))
# AbcDefGhiJklMnoPqrStu
```

It's a bit inelegant, but it seems to work, and would be more what you're looking for than above.

Comment: I'll certainly consider you confirming that "there is no way around this" as a satisfying answer.  Bummer that this case falls though the cracks of intuitive slicing.    Thanks

Comment: @ZwiTrader You could do `i-1 if i else None` instead of `i-1`. Or keep  the `i-1` but double down on the negatives, using `range(-len(string), 0, 3)`.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode TIL that's a thing. I've edited my answer accordingly, thanks for bringing that up

Comment: Yeah, `None` is simply the default, equivalent to omitting a value ([demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzknsbhYwdmKSwEI4uPTU0syS1Jz4@MVbBUKijLzSri4nDU0o9XT8vPVrazUkxKL1GP//wcA)). Did you try the negative range as well? It's unusual, but also simple and perhaps slightly faster.

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions @don't talk just code.  It's interesting to learn about `i-1 if i else None` as an option, but 'doubling down on the negatives' as you say is compact and gets right at what I was after in the first place.  Perfect.